How do I remove auto populated service label when using the open telemetry data dog exporter?
We have moved over from using the datadog agent with an open telemetry connector to using the open telemetry datadog exporter. We use a tag called 'service' that gets populated with the name of our kube apps. However, since the move over to the exporter we have found that another service label gets added to the metrics with the value "k8s". I believe it is being auto populated by data dog somehow. The docs I have find to be confusing on this topic. Is this likely to be what's happening? And, if so, how could I remove?
I have tried to remove the label using the attributes processor and still nothing. I have tried to set 'service.name'. I have also tried to set the datadog service label on my pods.

Hey Harvey, would you be able to add your collector config and a sample of the data in the question? You could also open a ticket in DD. Whatever better fits you
